# MongDB Atlas document size increased 16MB, update/delete option possibility?

Tags: mongodb, timeout, mongodb-atlas

I have met the 16MB limit for many documents in the collection, and I need to update the documents by deleting some nested arrays. Is there any option I can do it as both Atlas web app and MongoDB compass app are giving timeout error.

> connection unable to decode message length: read tcp i/o timeout Check
>   your query and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still facing this issue then they can use Robo 3T tool which gives the flexibility to modify the shell timeout.